# Android 12 turn bluetooth on

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

So.. i got all new permissions added in manifest file,

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"
    android:maxSdkVersion="30" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"
    android:maxSdkVersion="30" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"
    android:maxSdkVersion="30" />
<!-- Needed only if your app looks for Bluetooth devices. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS"/>

//Added an array with (maybe more than what i need) permissions
private static String[] PERMISSIONS_BLUETOOTH = {
        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS,
        Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN,
        Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT,
        Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE,
        Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH,
        Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED
};

//checking permission with user:
int permission1 = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, 
     Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH);

if (permission1 != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,PERMISSIONS_BLUETOOTH,1);
}

// got the results in 
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(.....)
```

I got this:

- android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION-0
- android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS-0
- android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN-0
- android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT-0
- android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE--1
- android.permission.BLUETOOTH--1
- android.permission.BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED--1

So i try to enable bluetooth.. as i have permissions now. with..

```
BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        mBluetoothAdapter.enable();
    }
```

But.. no doesnt do anything.. not error, not a log.. and of course.. it doesnt turn bluetooth on....    Am i missing something??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the user-facing method which is future-proof and works on all API levels.

```
if (bluetoothAdapter?.isEnabled == false) {
  val enableBtIntent = Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE)
  startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT)
}
```

See [Set up Bluetooth](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/setup) for details.

Comment: startActivityForResult is deprecated. What can be used as an alternative to capture the result

Answer (score 0):

The use of the `BluetoothAdapter.enable()` function is [highly regulated](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter#enable()) (for safety reasons) and most likely your application lacks one of the necessary requirements.

From an application point of view, it is better to ask the user to switch on Bluetooth via the system settings if this is required by your application and should not already be switched on.